# Only resize next (to the right) flex items in flexbox when resizing a flex item with 'css resize'

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, mutation-observers

I want to have a flexbox with eg. five boxes/items and when I resize (via css resize) the middle box, the boxes/items on the left should be untouched and the current box (the one being resized) and following boxes should be resized flexibly.

In the code below, when resizing the middle box/item, all others are resized also, which is not the required result. Only the ones on the right should be resized accordingly.
(target is latest browser)

---

**UPDATE**:

Had a stupid reference error in my original code from which code below was distilled. Updated the code below with something closer to the final answer. The only thing that confuses me now is that there are sometimes weird jumps in sizes at the beginning of a resize.

---

Code:

```js
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".flex-item");

let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type == "attributes" && mutation.oldValue.indexOf("width") === 0) {
      console.log(mutation);
      let el = mutation.target;
      let curWidth = window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('width');
      
      while (el = el.previousElementSibling) { 
        console.log(el);
              //1. all previous element siblings must be fixed in width (with their current width fixed during the resizing of target element) 
        if (el.className.indexOf('flexstop') === -1) {
          el.style.width = window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('width') + 'px';
          el.className += ' flexstop';
        }
      }
      el = mutation.target;
      while (el = el.nextElementSibling ) {
        console.log(el);
              //2. target element and all next element siblings must resize based on resizing target element
        el.className = el.className.replace(' flexstop', '');
      }
    }
  });
});


for(var x=0; x < boxes.length; x++)
{
  //boxes[x].style.width = window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('width') + 'px';
  observer.observe(boxes[x], {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter : ["style"],
    subtree : false,
    childlist : false,
    attributeOldValue : true
});
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
    
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;

}

.flex-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 20vw;
  
  background: tomato;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  
  overflow: scroll;
  resize: horizontal;
}

.flexstop {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: One of the things I tried to do (unsuccessfully) is setting the width on previous siblings to their actual computed width and set flex-grow and flex-shrink to 0 (via another css class definition that is set on all previous elements)

Comment: Have you noticed that there is an error in the JS of your snippet ?

Comment: I saw the error. It was not that relevant for the question itself, but corrected it in my update with also some new insights